For a disabled person's ring, how might a switch be added to the device that is waterproof and totally durable?
I have to cram a lot of electronics into a very, very tiny space. Microcontroller, battery, charging circuit, sensors, display, and an activation button into a ring on my finger. It's a device for supporting people with disabilities.
The processor will remain in low-power mode until activated. When activated, it will do its thing, then deactivate 30s later.
Activation is the problem. Waterproof momentary switches tend to be made with rubber or some other flimsy membrane that wouldn't hold up to being on my hand. It would be preferable if the device were permanently sealed. Something like an Oura Ring.
The only thing I have come up with so far is a surface-mounted, magnetically-activated reed switch. A ring on a different finger would have a magnet in it to trigger the switch. If there's a way to do this with capacitive touch that would be ultra-low power and wouldn't accidentally activate all the time, that would be fine, too.
I expect to have around 75mAh of power in the device, and that needs to be enough for two days of inactive use, so a touch sensor that drew more than 1mA (or caused the device to mistakenly activate more than a couple times per day) wouldn't work.

For something like this the design and partners you will need are extensive. And complete -- and I do mean complete -- details would be required. Vague phrases like do its thing are the diametric opposite and destroy any hope of useful help. You need close help from more than a few highly skilled manufacturing and design engineers. Or contact Oura to see if they may be willing to help in some way to head you in the right direction.

My kitchen scales run on a CR2032 cell for over a year, doing typically 10 weighings per day. The touch-sensitive scanning for the on switch must run at least 2 Hz, as they come on well sub-second when touched. So touch-scan alone would last for >> 2 years with that supply. That gives you a bound for what can be achieved.

You can get a number of MCUs that have built-in capacitive switch controllers.
Microchip, Silabs and WCH, at least, but shop around.
They work on the basis of capacitance change. The one I've used recently gives you a count of a few thousand and you can either set a threshold (and perhaps hysteresis) as fixed constants in your firmware or write some code to calibrate itself at power up (assuming it can be guaranteed there's no contact).
You're probably familiar with these as part of computer monitor controls and such like.
I don't know if you can work that into your physical limitations, but it does allow there to be no mechanical contacts and can be sealed against moisture. It's pretty easy to get ahold of a dev board and give it a shot, and there are design guidelines published by many of the suppliers.
